# How to retain style of elements in Datatable Jquery ui?

Tags: jquery, checkbox, datatables, styling

I've created a datatable using jquery.I've added checkbox in first column.
Everything works fine.

But when i click next or some page number in pagination the next page displays checkbox but css style is lost.Only first page of datatable displayed checkbox style.NExt pages show plain conventional checkboxes without style.

Guidance/Help from experts would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is probably that you're not just using .css but you have a global.js or similar that updates the styles when the page loads.

For example if you have this:

`$(document).ready(function () { $('#something').css(...); });`

It will CSS your elements when the page loads but not if anything changes.

When the datatable goes to page 2, it is doing a partial refresh, ie. only reloading the table and not the rest of the page. Therefore anything in global.js that is triggered upon loading the page to restyle buttons etc. is not executing.

You should run these methods manually as part of the update to correct the styles. There should be a client event you can hook into to do this.

Comment: I tried "$('#datatablex').bind('page', function () {" to detect partial page refresh and it detects the rows and its elements correctly.Tried setting the check box style but doesn't work.Although it gives(alert) values of each check-boxes on next,number,last pages correctly.

Comment: also currently i am trying with static data.Dynamic data not integrated yet.

Comment: You're going to have to paste some code, if the code that sets the checkbox style is running then there must be a bug in it.

Comment: i'm having this same problem, is there a solution available?